# How to make Ecto interpret/write local time instead of UTC for `timestamps` macro

Tags: timezone, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, timezone-offset

This is about integrating a database from a legacy app.
The legacy app is reading and writing timestamps (i.e. `created_at`, `updated_at` in local time of the host).

And while I'm fully aware that this should be highly avoided this behaviour cannot be changed.

Therefore the Elixir application that uses the same database must be configured to use local time as well.

[Ecto provides the `timestamps` macro](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v3.6.2/lib/ecto/schema.ex#L698) but it seems that I cannot make it work with local timestamps.
While it's possible to provide a type (i.e. `:naive_datetime` or `:utc_datetime`) both types seem to use the `utc_now()` function.

Also reading the fields might cause difficulties, since the date fields are defined as `timestamp without time zone` in the database.
Hence the database fields also should be interpreted as local time and not as UTC.

Comment: Local time on the server is most likely UTC. Are you sure it’s not? Because if it’s UTC you are safe.

Comment: Host and legacy application differ from the Elixir app. Therefore stored timestamps have an offset to UTC/Ecto. This is also the reason why I created the StackOverflow question in the first place.

Comment: That I understood. My question was _what actual timezone_ is set on the legacy host? There are big chances it’s UTC.

Comment: Have you tried the `autogenerate` option from the doc of the `timestamps` macro you mentioned? Probably something like `autogenerate: {DateTime, :now!, ["Europe/Copenhagen"]}`

Comment: I'm confused... a timestamp without a timezone is "naive", and frequently "no timezone" means no offset, or UTC.  Regardless, you should be able to use sabiwara's suggestion to point towards an arbitrary module/function to generate values consistent with your legacy database.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I probably still don't understand your question: so the actual timezone on the legacy host is Europe/Berne and the legacy app is using "local" time (hence the time zone of the host which is, again, Europe/Berne). And Europe/Berne is not UTC.
@sabiwara sounds very reasonable. It didn't work though (`(ArgumentError) :utc_datetime expects the time zone to be "Etc/UTC", got `#DateTime<2022-04-12 15:17:48.110619+02:00 CEST Europe/Copenhagen>`)

Comment: @Everett sabiwara's comment didn't work for me (see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71839351/how-to-make-ecto-interpret-write-local-time-instead-of-utc-for-timestamps-macr#comment126956015_71839351)). And I'm not quite sure what's confusing for you. I understood that a timestamp without timezone is called "naive" datetime in Elixir. This is not the point. I just want to have the local time persisted instead of UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Per @AlekseiMatiushkin, you should be able to use the `:autogenerate` for this, something like:

```
defmodule MyThing do

  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "things" do
    field(:something, :string, null: false)
    # ...
    timestamps(autogenerate: {MyThing, :local_time, []})
  end

  def local_time do
    DateTime.now!("Europe/Vienna") |> DateTime.to_naive()
  end

  # ...
end
```

If relying on the macro is too constrained for your use-case, you can manually write values to the fields (some languages call these mutations, virtual fields, or calculated fields). Something like:

```
defmodule MyThing do

  use Ecto.Schema

  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "things" do
    field(:something, :string, null: false)
    field(:my_timestamp_col, :map) # <-- or integer, or ???
    # ...
  end

  def changeset(thing, attrs) do
    thing
    |> cast(
         attrs,
         [
           :something,
           # ...
         ]
       )
    # validate, constraints, etc.
    |> calc_local_time()
  end



  defp calc_local_time(changeset) do
    case changeset do
      %Ecto.Changeset{
        valid?: true,
        changes: thing
      } ->
        put_change(thing, :my_timestamp_col, local_time())
      _ ->
        changeset
    end
  end

  def local_time do
    # add custom date/time calcs here
    DateTime.now!("Europe/Vienna") |> DateTime.to_naive()
  end
end
```

Hopefully you can find a solution leveraging the above patterns.